# Uso de Ñ en nombre de variables

Tags: c#

Tradicionalmente la recomendación para los nombres de variables y métodos en los lenguajes de programación, siempre ha sido no utilizar caracteres especiales incluyendo la Ñ.

Siguiendo la tradición aún sigo llamando "annio" las variables "año", incluso otros programadores usan "ano","anno","anho","year", etc.; aún cuando actualmente Visual Studio permite llamar la variable "Año" sin ningún problemas al compilar.

Me preguntaba que me impide utilizar la palabra "año" y quisiera conocer si hay algún estándar o buenas/malas prácticas definidas para usar ese tipo de caracteres "especiales" en el nombre de una variable: lo bueno, lo malo y lo feo; cualquier referencia o comentario al respecto me resultará útil.

Comment: Es potencialmente incompatible con otros sistemas presentes y futuros y dudo que ningún standard lo contemple, no lo hagas, te ahorraras problemas.

Comment: "dudo que ningún standard lo contemple" C# lo contempla https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Unicode_variable_names#C.23

Comment: Después de ver estos ejemplos tengo mis dudas Amau: https://twitter.com/Stephan007/status/481001490463866880/photo/1

Comment: Aquí encontré otra discusión sobre el uso de caracteres UNICODE en identificadores, para fórmulas matemáticas, creo que en el presente ya no es tan incompatible como solía ser, agradezco tu respuesta @ArnauCastellví <http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16010/is-it-bad-to-use-unicode-characters-in-variable-names>

Comment: Va bien saberlo, pero yo no me arriesgaría.
Otro problema es si tu código debe poder modificarlo otra persona sin el teclado adecuado.

Comment: Esta pregunta no esta pidiendo opinion??? Tiene alguna respuesta valida?? si el compilador compila, aun usando caracteres "raros", cual es el problema???

Comment: Yo, solo por respeto a quien pueda leer el codigo en el futuro no utilizo ni ñ ni ningun simbolo que no sea "internacional" por decirlo de alguna manera.

Comment: Aunque pones el caso de C#, seguramente hay otros lenguajes que admiten la ñ en el nombre de una variable, ¿deberíamos etiquetar la pregunta como [tag:lenguaje-agnóstico]?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Me preguntaba que me impide utilizar la palabra "año" y quisiera conocer sus opiniones al respecto: lo bueno, lo malo y lo feo; cualquier opinión o comentario al respecto me resultará útil.

#### 1) Trabajar con un equipo internacional.

Cuando trabajas en un equipo internacional, utilizar según qué caracteres puede ser una pesadilla para otros miembros del equipo; no todos [los teclados](https://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/ml-mua/test/kbd-all.html) tienen la misma facilidad para acceder a (por ejemplo) nuestra amada N con peineta; así que si tú usas este teclado:

[image]

Y tu compañero de trabajo Norteamericano usa este:
[image]

Para tu compañero va a ser un problema acceder a la `Ñ`. Y si trabajas con equipos que tienen alfabetos muy diferentes el problema crece exponencialmente:

```
int 入玉口千 = 0xFf800000;
int 人王ロ干 = 0xF8000000;
```

Te juro que ambas variables son diferentes, fíjate bien en los nombres. Yo la verdad es que no tengo buen ojo para el Japonés, así que no creo que pueda usar la variable correcta.

```
Decimal año = 2000; // 365 días
Decimal ano = 2016; // Parte de mi anatomía
```

Para mí es muy evidente la diferencia entre ambas cosas, tal vez otros compañeros de trabajo de otros países no lo tengan tan claro.

```
bool flag = false; // это не является необходимым
```

Nunca sabré qué pretendía decir mi compañero Pavlov Provotorov.

```
public void Iͬͩͩ̽ͦ̍҉̣͙ņ̨̠̩͈̰͎̹̼̎̊͑̌̀vͪ͐ͮ̒ͣ͒͡͏̠̤̱̪̥ợ̟͔ͭ̃͌c͙̣̱̏̿ͯ̓̅̋͛a̵̝̲͚̭̗ͬ̊ͅ_̷̱̻̤̪̝̥̠͉̂̐͊ͣ͡͝ͅâ̬̱̳̮͆ͭ̕͢ͅl̟͕̳̣ͯͦ̎ͯ̄ͩ͗ͯ̕̕͞_̽ͪ̇ͫ̆҉̧̱͚̻̝̠d̮̗̜͈̝̩̦͆̓̑͐e͂҉̩̩͓͠m̛̠̣͈̠̩̂̂͋̅ô̧͍͑͌͛n̂͏͙̭i̧͉̋ͤ̏̐̍͊͘o̶͕̹̳̟͇͇̝͉ͮͩ͋͆()
```

No quiero ni pensar qué puede hacer esta función.

```
bool  = check_error();
if () { // shit happens
```

A alguien le parecerá gracioso, [a mi me parece de mal gusto](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106050/is-unicode-pile-of-poo-considered-nsfw).

#### 2) Compañeros excesivamente apegados a la correctitud.

Yo me he encontrado con problemas como el de la `Ñ` con compañeros de trabajo matemáticos que escribían código como este:

```
double π = 3.14159265;
```

Aún siendo π el símbolo correcto para esa constante, escribirlo en el código es <strike>peor que un grano en el culo</strike> incómodo; yo solía tener un archivo de texto abierto con los símbolos que no podía escribir para copia-pegarlos cuando lo necesitaba; pero eso no hacía mi vida más fácil ni cómoda.

Bueno, pero los IDE ayudan a solucionar este problema ¿no?, supón que tienes:

```
class MathConstants
{
    public const double π = 3.14159265;
    public const double e = 2.71828;
    public const double α = ...
    public const double δ = ...
    public const double φ = ...
    public const double γ = ...
    public const double λ = ...
}
```

Cabría esperar que escribiendo en el IDE `MathConstants.` me saliera tras el punto `.` una lista de las constantes matemáticas y así me ahorro de escribirlas, pero en la mayoría de IDE que usaba por aquel entonces en el mejor de los casos salía una lista de carácteres desconocidos (`?` o `□`), incluso usé una versión de Eclipse que se cerraba (¡sin guardar los archivos modificados!) si abría una lista de miembros de un objeto con identificadores *extraños*, así que acabé cambiando el código a:

```
class MathConstants
{
    public const double Pi              = 3.14159265;
    public const double Euler           = 2.71828;
    public const double Phi             = ...
    public const double EulerMascheroni = ...
    public const double Conway          = ...
}
```

Que además de ser más amigable con el IDE, hacía que no tuviera que aprenderme el alfabeto griego y es más explicativo que variables de una sola letra.

#### 3) La codificación y los sistemas de versionado.

Otro problema que he vivido con *caracteres extraños* en el código fuente (ya sea en comentarios como en identificadores) es que al subir el código al sistema de [control de versiones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_de_versiones), los archivos con *caracteres extraños* se corrompían y al hacer check-out o update todo dejaba de compilar.

Normalmente este problema provenía de las diferentes codificaciones de archivo de texto entre plataformas (suelo trabajar en Windows y alojar el servidor de versionado en Linux) se soluciona configurando adecuadamente el sistema de control de versiones y teniendo en cuenta las características de la plataforma en que el servidor de código está alojado... o simplemente no usando *caracteres extraños*.

#### Resumen.

La letra `Ñ` `ñ` es sólo la punta del iceberg en un problema algo más complejo que es el uso de caracteres unicode en código fuente. Estos caracteres pueden dar lugar a problemas sin que añadan una mejora significativa a la calidad del código, así que su uso puede considerarse una pequeña mejora a cambio de un gran problema.

Por otro lado, si permitimos letras del alfabeto español como la eñe o la ce con cedilla (`ç`), no tenemos motivos para prohibir letras en otros idiomas, lo cuál fácilmente escala a problemas mayores. Si trabajamos en un equipo internacional algunos programadores se sentirán más cómodos programando en su idioma y eso es bueno para ellos y malo para el equipo (lo siento Pavlov, no aguanto tus comentarios en cirílico)... y esto sin contar que cada país puede tener teclados diferentes o que el IDE que usemos puede no estar preparado para trabajar con estos caracteres o que incluso estos caracteres *vuelvan loco* al compilador.

Y aunque no trabajemos en un equipo internacional, hay que considerar que la mayoría de documentación sobre programación se encuentra en Inglés, si tenemos código escrito con caracteres exclusivos en nuestro idioma hará más difícil para la comunidad internacional entender nuestro código cuando pidamos ayuda sobre el mismo.

#### Conclusión.

Yo no veo una ventaja significativa en usar `Ñ` o cualquier otro caracter exótico en el código fuente, pero siempre que todas las personas que trabajen con dicho código estén cómodas tampoco veo motivo para prohibirlo.

Comment: Gran primera inclusión de Zalgo en el sitio y excelentes los ejemplos (y sí me pareció gracioso antes que de mal gusto).

Comment: No hables muy fuerte de Z̶͜àl͝͡g̵̛҉o̧̧ o tendremos problemas.

Comment: Nŏ̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆ŏ̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆ŏ̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆ŏ̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆ŏ̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆ŏ̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆ŏ̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆̆

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con los dos primeros puntos. El tercero es bueno para tener en cuenta, pero no debería ser un factor para decidir "no usar caracteres extraños" (notar además que la autoprohibición abarcaría todo el código fuente -literales, comentarios- e incluso otros archivos de texto)

Comment: Muy buena explicación @PaperBirdMaster te la agradezco, creo que ahora el reto está en la diversidad de las personas y sus culturas que forman los equipos de trabajo; y coincido en que actualmente lo más cómodo es limitarnos a caracteres ASCII.

Comment: @leonbloy tienes toda la razón. Yo comento que en mi experiencia eso me ha dado problemas, evidentemente hay más soluciones a parte de la prohibición de *caracteres extraños* y éstas deben evaluarse pero como bien señalas, mi 3r punto es para tener en cuenta no para forzar una prohibición. Mi añecdota es en un `std::cout << "NO HAGAS ESTO MUÑON!!";` que esa `Ñ` causaba errores de compilación en el servidor de compilación (alojado en una máquina Linux)

Comment: me he reído bastante leyendo tu artículo =) Qué pensáis de la sintaxis cani, choni? Valdría para hacer código? `var mMivVaAriAbBleShuUuLaA` XD

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo tu pregunta da para un debate interesante, [Notación Húngara](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_h%C3%BAngara), todas las variantes de [CamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) y todas las variantes de [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) tienen pros y contras... sin embargo creo que SOes no es el lugar adecuado para dicho debate :)

Comment: Yo creo que vi algo raro xD *Decimal ano = 2016; // Parte de mi anatomía*, tantos huecos tienes xD. Por otro lado, MUY Buena respuesta :)

Comment: @Victor-Random `ano = 2016` no se refiere a la cantidad de anos si no al diámetro medido en *plikins* métricos.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster yo solo quería ser popular :( jejejeje que son plikins?

Answer (score 9):

Es cuestión muy discutida. La mayoría de los programadores tenemos, efectivamente, la tradición de evitar caracteres "raros" (no ASCII) en los identificadores (incluso en nombres de archivos...)

Del lado "sólo ASCII": esa tradición se siente sana. Se evitan potenciales conflictos con distintas codificaciones cuando se desarrolla en equipo  (eg: algunos desarrolladores usan UTF-8, otros ISO-8859-1, otros UTF-16...) o incluso cuando se compila (el compilador debe estar de acuerdo con el editor. También es sano para cuando uno quiere compartir código (snippets) o hacer preguntas en sitios públicos que se manejan principalmente en inglés (SO, sin ir más lejos). [*]

Del lado "todo vale": estamos en 2016. La mayoría de los lenguajes (C# entre ellos) soportan identificadores con caracters Unicode sin problemas. Y Unicode ya no debería ser un misterio para ningún programador no principiante, y todos los programadores en Español deberíamos estar concientes de que cuando editamos un archivo de texto (potencialmente con caracters no ASCII) estamos usando una codificación determinada (y siempre debemos decidirla nosotros de entrada, no dejar que nuestro sistema operativo o nuestra IDE lo haga por las suyas).
Desde este punto de vista, usar Unicode en los identificadores es, en cierta manera, aconsejable: porque nos obliga a ser concientes y consistentes en las codificaciones (y a familiarizarnos con Unicode, si antes le teníamos resquemor). Hoy en día se aconseja fuertemente optar por **UTF-8** para el código fuente.

Por mi parte, no veo objeciones contra usar `año` como identificador en `C#`. Pero si haces eso y, cuando te pregunto *"¿Qué codificación estás usando para tu código fuente?"* no sabes responderme, entonces sí estamos en problemas.

[*] Nótese, de paso, que la mayoría de estos argumentos también desaconsejarían el uso de caracteres no-ASCII no sólo en identificadores sino en valores literales y aun en comentarios - lo cual parece demasiado restrictivo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @leonbloy me es de gran utilidad, me queda claro que la restricción ya no se encuentra en el compilador, sino que la barrera sería en la configuración no homogenea de los editores de cada programador.

Answer (score 9):

Llego tarde, pero me gustaría aportar mi granito de arena a esta cuestión.

En mi opinión, se debería evitar usar no ya carácteres no ASCII en los identificadores del código... es que directamente se debería evitar usar el idioma español. Todo debería estar en inglés. Estamos en un mundo globalizado, especialmente en el ámbito del software, y nunca sabes quién va a estar trabajando en tu código en el futuro.

En el caso de proyectos de código abierto la cosa está bastante clara: el código va a estar disponible para todo el mundo desde el primer momento y sería una verdadera lástima que todos los programadores del mundo que no hablan tu idioma no sean capaces de examinarlo - y por tanto tampoco serán capaces de enviarte sugerencias de mejora o pull requests (lo cual es también malo para el propio autor del código).

Pero aún en el caso de código propietario desarrollado por una empresa pequeña que tiene una única oficina y todos los empleados son locales, resulta beneficioso tener todo el código en inglés. ¿Y si dentro de cinco años la empresa ha crecido y decide contratar empleados remotos en otros lugares del planeta? ¿Y si un señor inglés se viene a vivir a España y resulta que es un excelente programador y quiere trabajar en tu empresa (esto yo lo he vivido)? Si el código está en español sólo será posible contratar empleados hispanohablantes.

Y hay otra cuestión: si quieres pegar parte del código en alguna web para pedir ayuda (sea el Stack Overflow original, sea algún foro de soporte de alguna compañía) y lo tienes todo en español, vas a tener que traducirlo todo cada vez.

Así es como lo veo yo, hace años que [todo mi código](https://github.com/konamiman) está 100% en inglés y me he encontrado con que todo son ventajas. **Pero** entiendo que no todo es blanco o negro en la vida, y habrá circunstancias en las que el código deberá estar necesariamente en español por la razón que sea. En estos casos yo coincido con PaperBirdMaster: evitaría como la peste cualquier caracter no ASCII, y escribiría "año" como "anyo". Programar ya es lo suficientemente complicado y las herramientas (IDEs, repositorios, entornos de integración continua...) ya dan bastantes problemas por sí mismas, como para encima arriesgarse a tener problemas con la codificación de los ficheros de las fuentes.

Comment: ¡Más vale tarde que ñuñca!

Comment: :3 jijijijijijiji @Mariano tiene razon jeejeje :'3

Comment: Te voto positivo por el buen aporte, pero estoy en completo desacuerdo con la argumentación.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Todo lo que diga Konamiman es cierto.

Comment: @PaulVargas estaré encantado de discutir por qué creo que Konamiman no está en lo cierto en una sala de chat.

Comment: @PaulVargas Pues atento a lo que voy a decir ahora: "No todo lo que dice Konamiman es cierto". MIND BLOWN! :-)

Comment: @Konamiman No hay problema. Te creo. :P -- Por cierto, +1

Comment: Es muy debatible el argumento de @Konamiman pero le dí otro +1 por aportar y enriquecer la discusión

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta cortita: **programa siempre en inglés**. No pongas "año", ni "annio" ni mucho menos "ano", sino "year".

Algunas ventajas:

- Es más compacto que otros idiomas ("*driver*" vs "*controlador*").
- Si quieres compartir tu código, el inglés es lo universal.
- Si copias funciones en inglés para añadirlas a tu código, te ahorras traducirlas.
- Normalmente, las API suelen estar en inglés, con lo que programando en el mismo idioma se gana uniformidad y legibilidad ("*upload(archivoPrueba)*" vs "*upload(testFile)*").
- Te acostumbras enseguida.
- Ah, y te ahorras el problemas de los caracteres ASCII>128.

Comment: El argumento de ahorrar letras tenía sentido en los años 70 cuando nos pagaban por líneas y teníamos pantallas de 11 pulgadas con resolución 80 columnas 25 líneas :P

Comment: @ PaperBirdMaster Jeje, algo de razón tienes, pero sigo prefiriendo ahorrar texto.

Comment: En ese caso, escribe en Japonés, `void` se escribe con 3 ideogramas (ボイド) en lugar de 4, `public` con 2 (公共)  en lugar de 6,`class` con 3 (クラス) en lugar de 5 y ¡`static` con 2 (静的) en lugar de 6! ;P

Comment: @ PaperBirdMaster Para esos ejemplo, vale. Pero el japones es menos "denso" o compacto que el español y el inglés (http://medina-psicologia.ugr.es/cienciacognitiva/?p=329) Aparte de que con ideogramas no programan ni los chinos.

Comment: Estoy trabajando con un equipo Chino, y he pillado unos pocos comentarios en jiǎntǐzì xD

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dices no hay ninguna restricción en cuanto a C#, pero si la hay culturalmente. Si tu estás seguro que tu equipo de trabajo va a ser siempre en español, bien puedes usar la Ñ. Ahora esto te va a llevar a pensar en qué hacer con los acentos, ahí es dónde se complica un poco más, ya que no todos conocen bien el uso de los acentos y te puede llevar a que haya diferentes variables declaradas que quieran referencias al mismo objeto.