# Error al compilar programa C en ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N_BITS 3
// argc : Cantidad de argumentos (Contando ejectuable);
// argv : Array de char* y con los argumentos introducidos;
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned int i, mask = 0700;
    struct stat buff;
    struct passwd* pwd;
    struct group* grp;
    struct tm* time;
    static char* perm[] = {"---","--x","-w-","-wx","r--","r-x","rw-","rwx"};
    printf("_______________________________________________________________________\n");
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if ((stat(argv[1], &buff)) != -1)
        {
            printf("Permisos de %s: ", argv[1]);
            for (i=3; i; --i)
            {
                printf("%3s",perm[(buff.st_mode & mask) >> (i-1)*N_BITS]);
                mask >>= N_BITS;
            }
            putchar('\n');
            //Obtiene datos del struct en base al UID obtenido de /etc/passwd
            pwd = getpwuid(buff.st_uid);
            //Obtiene datos del struct en base al GID obtenido de /etc/group
            grp = getgrgid(buff.st_gid);
            printf("Usuario: %s Grupo: %s\n", pwd->pw_name, grp->gr_name);
            time = localtime(&buff.st_atime); / /Obtención de fecha de creación de fichero
            printf("Fecha de creación: %s", asctime(time));
            time = localtime(&buff.st_mtime); //Reinicialización de estructura y obtención de fecha de último acceso
            printf("Fecha de último acceso: %s", asctime(time));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nERROR: No se encuentra el fichero/directorio\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("_______________________________________________________________________\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file_name\n", argv[0]);
    }
}
```

Pues eso, estoy haciendo un programa sencillo pero me da ese error y estoy un poco patinando.

Comment: Por favor publica tu código en vez de imágenes, es mucho mas fácil de entender,

Comment: Hola @Ald. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor [edit] la pregunta e incluir el código y el mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para [edit] debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Comment: He editado la pregunta para incluir el código publicado por el OP como respuesta, y he eliminado la imagen. Sigue haciendo falta una explicación de qué es lo que no funciona, y si hay errores involucrados, el mensaje de error de marras.

Comment: You forgot to include the error message

Comment: [¿Qué error te da?](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/klHLRcPO7HXULa1s) a mi me avisa de que `main` no debe devolver `void`, que el comentario de la línea 35 está mal y que no entiende los acentos en los literales de texto.

Answer (score 2):

[Compilando con gcc 4.8.2](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/klHLRcPO7HXULa1s) me da los siguientes errores:

> ```
> 10:6: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain]
>  void main(int argc, char* argv[])
>   ^
>  In function 'main':
> 47: error: expected expression before '/' token
>          time = localtime(&buff.st_atime); / /Obtención de fecha de creación de fichero
>                                            ^
> 35:47: error: stray '\303' in program
> 35:47: error: stray '\263' in program
> 35:47: error: stray '\303' in program
> 35:47: error: stray '\263' in program
> ```

Básicamente tienes un comentario mal puesto en la línea 47 y la o acentuada (`ó`) de `creación` no le está gustando al compilador (algo ya [comentado como posible problema aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/opiniones-sobre-uso-de-%c3%91-en-nombre-de-variables-en-c/22393#22393)).

Corrigiendo todos esos problemas, el programa funciona con normalidad y muestra:

> ```
> _______________________________________________________________________
> Permisos de test.txt: rw-------
> Usuario: test Grupo: test
> Fecha de creacion: Fri Oct 14 19:21:13 2016
> Fecha de último acceso: Fri Oct 14 19:21:12 2016
> _______________________________________________________________________
> ```

Los errores son MUY auto-explicativos, no deberías tener problemas en entenderlos dedicando un poco de tiempo a analizarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Los caracteres acentuados no son un problema dentro de un comentario, el problema es que el comentario no es considerado como tal. Ese es puntualmente tú error. Adicionalmente si `main` es tipo `int` entonces debes devolver un entero al shell. Esto último es sólo una advertencia pero no es menor ya que en cierta parte devuelves 1:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N_BITS 3
// argc : Cantidad de argumentos (Contando ejectuable);
// argv : Array de char* y con los argumentos introducidos;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned int i, mask = 0700;
    struct stat buff;
    struct passwd* pwd;
    struct group* grp;
    struct tm* time;
    static char* perm[] = {"---","--x","-w-","-wx","r--","r-x","rw-","rwx"};
    printf("_______________________________________________________________________\n");
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if ((stat(argv[1], &buff)) != -1)
        {
            printf("Permisos de %s: ", argv[1]);
            for (i=3; i; --i)
            {
                printf("%3s",perm[(buff.st_mode & mask) >> (i-1)*N_BITS]);
                mask >>= N_BITS;
            }
            putchar('\n');
            //Obtiene datos del struct en base al UID obtenido de /etc/passwd
            pwd = getpwuid(buff.st_uid);
            //Obtiene datos del struct en base al GID obtenido de /etc/group
            grp = getgrgid(buff.st_gid);
            printf("Usuario: %s Grupo: %s\n", pwd->pw_name, grp->gr_name);
            time = localtime(&buff.st_atime); // Obtención de fecha de creación de fichero
            printf("Fecha de creación: %s", asctime(time));
            time = localtime(&buff.st_mtime); //Reinicialización de estructura y obtención de fecha de último acceso
            printf("Fecha de último acceso: %s", asctime(time));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nERROR: No se encuentra el fichero/directorio\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("_______________________________________________________________________\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file_name\n", argv[0]);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```