# Es recomendable usar la " Ñ" como declaracion en Java o cualquier otro lenguaje?

Tags: java

Hola es recomendable usar la letra Ñ como nombre de variable, por ejemplo 
"niño" o algo asi?, o es mejor usar "boy" cuales son las consecuecias si declaro asi un objeto,clase o variable.

Gracias por su atencion y espero sus comentarios.

Comment: Yo tuve la misma pregunta, independientemente del lenguaje, te recomiendo leer las respuestas que me enviaron: [Opiniones sobre uso de Ñ en nombre de variables en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/opiniones-sobre-uso-de-%C3%91-en-nombre-de-variables-en-c/73376#73376).

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/47026)

Comment: Entiendo, solo que la respuesta es muy extensa y lleva diferentes puntos de opinión igual de válidos, por eso preferí solo incluír el hipervínculo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He ido a las [especificaciones de Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) para intentar responder a la pregunta.

Allí se afirma lo siguiente sobre los identificadores:

> Un identificador es una secuencia de longitud ilimitada de letras y
>   dígitos de Java, el primero de los cuales debe ser una letra de Java.

```
Identifier:
     IdentifierChars pero no palabra clave o BooleanLiteral o NullLiteral

IdentifierChars:
     JavaLetter
     IdentifierChars JavaLetterOrDigit

JavaLetter:
     cualquier carácter Unicode que es una letra de Java (ver más abajo)

JavaLetterOrDigit:
     cualquier carácter Unicode que es una letra o dígitos de Java (ver más abajo)
```

Una "**`letra de Java`**" es un caracter para el que el método `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart (int)` devuelve verdadero.

Una "**`letra de Java o dígitos`**" es un caracter para el que el método `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart (int)` devuelve verdadero.

Las "letras de Java" incluyen mayúsculas y minúsculas ASCII, letras latinas AZ (\ u0041- \ u005a) y z (\ u0061- \ u007a), y, por razones históricas, el subrayado ASCII (_ o \ u005f) y el signo de dólar ($ o \ u0024). El carácter $ se debe utilizar solamente en el código fuente generado de forma mecánica o, en raras ocasiones, para acceder a los nombres preexistentes para los sistemas heredados.

Los "**`dígitos Java`**" incluyen los dígitos 0-9 ASCII (\ u0030- \ u0039).

Letras y dígitos se pueden extraer de todo el conjunto de caracteres Unicode, que soporta la mayoría de la escritura de guiones en uso en el mundo de hoy, incluyendo los conjuntos grandes para chino, japonés y coreano. Esto permite a los programadores utilizar en sus programas identificadores que estén escritos en su lengua materna.

**Un identificador no puede tener la misma ortografía (secuencia de caracteres Unicode) como palabra clave ([§3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)), boolean literal ([§3.10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.3)), o el nulo literal, o se produce un error de tiempo de compilación ([§3.10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7)).**

Dos identificadores son los mismos sólo si son idénticos, es decir, tienen el mismo carácter Unicode para cada letra o dígito. Los identificadores que tienen la misma apariencia externa sin embargo, puede ser diferente.

---

En consecuencia, de acuerdo a la especificación del lenguaje, **es lícito** usar  Ñ o cualquier otro carácter, como acentos y caracteres aún más extraños como identificadores de Java (ver código de más abajo). **Pero el que sea lícito no significa que sea conveniente o recomendable hacerlo,** sobre todo por el problema mismo de la codificación. Si en el entorno de creación no puede haber confusiones, podría haberlas cuando el programa se ejecute en un entorno diferente... si bien se trata de una posibilidad difícil de determinar, no veo motivo para correr riesgos. (Recuerdo haber visto casos en los que el programa fallaba debido a la concurrencia de dos factores: el uso de `ñ` o palabras acentuadas en los identificadores y una codificación en el entorno que interpretaba mal esos caracteres... Es un escenario no muy difícil de que se produzca).

Yo no usaría ñ, espacios, acentos u otros caracteres como identificadores de Java, o como nombres de columnas o tablas de bases de datos para evitar posibles problemas de mal interpretación debido a la codificación establecida a la hora de ejecutar el programa en diversos escenarios.

En mi caso particular, dentro de Java prefiero usar nombres en inglés, pues me parece acorde con la convención de nombres, en la cual una práctica que todos conocemos es la de los *getters* y *setters*, cuyos nombres siempre empiezan por `get...` , `set...` creo que es mejor no quedarse a medio camino y usar todo en inglés, así por ejemplo: `getYear()`, `setYear()`... Pero eso ya depende de las costumbres de cada uno.

#### Código interesante

Este código muestra todos los caracteres permitidos como identificadores en Java, son en total **24350** :) :

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/IWNWWP14127)

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


    for (int i = 0; i < Character.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        if (Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(i)) {
            System.out.println("i = " + i + ": " + (char) i);
        }
    }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunos lenguajes de programación que soportan la codificación de la Ñ (utf-8). Sin embargo, hay otros muchos lenguajes que no.

Yo te recomiendo que nunca pongas ninguna ñ de la misma forma que no tienes que poner acentos, ya que la codificación que utilizan los lenguajes de programación no suelen soportarla y a la larga solo traen problemas.

Comment: Francisco Romero, Gracias por tu comentario.