# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in PDO PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

Buen día comunidad, tengo este problema al querer guardar datos en mi base de datos, estoy creando un SignUp, pero desde que agregue "FDia", "FMes" y "FAño" a mi formulario y se almacene mediante `PHP`, me arroja ese error, ya investigue en otras preguntas relacionadas y nada.

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AureaEdu\classes\DB.php:10 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AureaEdu\classes\DB.php(10):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AureaEdu\RegAlumn.php(12): DB::query('INSERT INTO
>   reg...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AureaEdu\classes\DB.php on line 10

Este el PHP

```
<?php
include('classes/DB.php');
if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $genero = $_POST['genero'];
        $FDia = $_POST['FDia'];
        $FMes = $_POST['FMes'];
        $FAño = $_POST['FAño'];

        DB::query('INSERT INTO registroalumnos 
                   VALUES (
                            null, 
                            :name, 
                            :email, 
                            :password, 
                            :genero, 
                            :FDia, 
                            :FMes, 
                            :FAño)',
                    array(
                            ':name'=>$name, 
                            ':email'=>$email, 
                            ':password'=>$password, 
                            ':genero'=>$genero, 
                            ':FDia'=>$FDia, 
                            ':FMes'=>$FMes, 
                            ':FAño'=>$FAño)
                          );
        echo "Success!";
```

Y aquí está donde esta lo del arreglo:

```
    <?php class DB {
        private static function connect() {
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=aureaedu;charset=utf8', 'root', '1592854Aa');
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $pdo;
        }
        public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
                $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute($params);
                // $data = $statement->fetchAll();
                // return $data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No estoy muy seguro pero tal vez es porque estas poniendo un `null` que supongo que sera el `id` de tu tabla, pero en el array no lo defines, si en tu base de datos lo tienes autoincrementable, puedes omitirlo

Comment: Debería revisar [Uso de Ñ en nombre de variables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-%C3%91-en-nombre-de-variables/72303#72303) sin duda es un tema importante a tener en cuenta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error podría solucionarse simplemente con modificar el nombre de su variable , el nombre del campo en su tabla y el atributo `name` del `input` que trae el año desde el `HTML`

```
//En Tabla SQL , las Variable PHP y en el name de su input en su HTML también
FAño -> FAnio
```

**Código**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$genero = $_POST['genero'];
$FDia = $_POST['FDia'];
$FMes = $_POST['FMes'];
$FAnio = $_POST['FAnio'];

$query = 'INSERT INTO registroalumnos VALUES (null, :name, :email,:password,
           :genero, :FDia, :FMes, :FAnio)';
$params  = array(':name'=>$name, ':email'=>$email, ':password'=>$password, 
           ':genero'=>$genero, ':FDia'=>$FDia, ':FMes'=>$FMes, ':FAnio'=>$FAnio );

DB::query($query, $params);
```

> Como mencioné en los comentario , debería evitar el uso de la letra
>   `ñ` para variables y nombre de campos , [Revisar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-%C3%91-en-nombre-de-variables/72303#72303)

Comment: Es cierto había visto mal. En efecto, se pasan aparte la consulta SQL y el array. No estoy acostumbrado a pasar cadenas completas a métodos por lo que se me escapan detalles cuando alguien lo hace así. Borro comentario anterior.

Comment: @A.Cedano pasa a veces, Igual estaba revisando a detalle 3:)

Comment: De verdad, muchísimas gracias!!! me funcionó !! remplace el nombre de las variables, atributos y de la table, me has salvado! jaja. Ahora, una duda, por qué no acepta la "ñ"?

Comment: @AntonioAlejos al parecer hay un error de codificación en el `execute` de `PDO` para estos caracteres , Igual mi recomendación la deje en la parte final de mi respuesta. No solo para este caso , debería evitar el uso de la letra **ñ** o letras con tilde. _(con la excepción de casos extraordinarios )_ Saludos.