# ¿Como puedo leer un json en un webservice en java que contenga por ejemplo una ó?

Tags: java, json, webservice

Estoy usando esta annotation en el metodo

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/impuesto", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
```

y al enviarle el siguiente json:

> {    "Código": "118",    "impuesto": "339" }

me informa el siguiente error por la ó:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid
>   UTF-8 middle byte 0x43f364

He probado tambien con:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/impuestos", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")

@RequestMapping(value = "/impuestos", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)

@RequestMapping(value = "/impuestos", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json,charset=UTF-8"})
```

Siempre dandome error

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que lo que manda el cliente es también UTF-8? En cualquier caso recomiendo no usar nombres de atributos con tildes o caracteres extraños

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22393/22851

Comment: No hay ningún problema con tener una clave con diacríticos dentro de un JSON. El problema es que se está generando el caracter `0x43f364` que es inválido, y rompe la codificación... Deberías ver cómo se está generando ese JSON, el error está ahí. Probablemente se esté codificando como Latin-1, que genera un formato incorrecto para UTF

Comment: Exactamente como dijo Mariano el problema es la codificación del json (request), estoy usando el SOAPUI, le agregue -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 al archivo soapUI-4.6.0/bin/soapUI-4.6.0.vmoptions y funciono correctamente, gracias por la pronta respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se logra agregando un @JsonProperty al objeto que hace mapping al JSON que recibe tu request

No es necesario especificar el charset como lo estás haciendo actualmente. Eso sería en caso de que quisieras mostrar el JSON en formato HTML

Tu controller sería algo así:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/loadjson.action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Object> getJson(@RequestBody ImpuestoObj impuesto) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    result.put("success", true);
    result.put("obj",impuesto);
    return result;
}
```

Donde ImpuestoObj es el objeto que va a recibir tu JSON y es por eso que lleva la anotación @RequestBody

Tu POJO que le pusimos ImpuestoObj en este ejemplo sería del siguiente modo

```
package org.eclipse.che.examples;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class ImpuestoObj {

private String impuesto;
@JsonProperty(value="Código")
private String codigo;

public void setImpuesto(String impuesto) {
    this.impuesto = impuesto;
}
public String getImpuesto() {
    return this.impuesto;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
public String getCodigo() {
    return this.codigo;
}
```

}

es importante que pongas la anotación @JsonProperty al miembro que quieres que haga mapping con tu propiedad y en el value incluir el acento. Este tiene que ser idéntico al nombre del campo en el JSON para que se pueda mapear correctamente en tu objeto

Comment: Excelente la respuesta, pero el nombre lo traigo desde una consulta de la base de datos, lo tendre en cuenta. Gracias

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que lo traes desde una consulta? Sería bueno que marcaras la pregunta como correcta si respondió tu duda así ayudas a la comunidad. Saludos