# No recibe el valor de mi campo contraseña, lo toma como nulo

Tags: jsp, struts

Al procesar el formulario, no recibe el valor de mi campo contraseña, lo toma como nulo.

Este es mi codigo jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 >Ingrese al sistema</h1>
    <s:form action="ingresar">

        <s:textfield label="Ingrese su usuario" name="usuario" size="10"></s:textfield>    
        <s:textfield label="Password" name="contraseña"></s:textfield>
        <s:submit label="Ingresar" value="Ingresar"></s:submit>

    </s:form>
</body>
```

este es mi clase Java:

```
package action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class usuario extends ActionSupport {

//Declarar los atributos

private String usuario;
private String contraseña;

//Metodo execute



@Override
public String execute() throws Exception { 
    return "ok"; 
}




//Metodo de get y set

public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public String getContraseña() {
    return contraseña;
}

public void setContraseña(String contraseña) {
    this.contraseña = contraseña;
}


//Metodo de validacion

@Override
public void validate(){

   if(usuario==null||usuario.equals("")){
       addFieldError("usuario", "Ingrese su usuario por favor");
   }
    if(!usuario.startsWith("i2016")){
       addFieldError("usuario", "Debe empezar con i2016");
   }
   if(contraseña==null||contraseña.equals("")){
       addFieldError("contraseña", "Ingrese su contraseña por favor");
   }


}
}
```

Así se ve mi formulario:

[image: captura de pantalla del formulario]

Answer (score 0):

Tiene toda la pinta de que el problema es la **ñ** de contraseña, que por un tema de codificación se pierde por el camino en la respuesta. Prueba a cambiar de nombre el campo (`contrasenna`, por ejemplo).

No es una buena idea usar la ñ en el código, lamentablemente en el mundo de la programación el lenguaje dominante es el inglés y cualquier carácter que se salga de los usados en este idioma [es problemático](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-%C3%91-en-nombre-de-variables/)

Comment: estimado , cambie mi campo y me sale el mismo error.

Comment: Pregunta un poco tonta, pero necesaria ¿cambiaste el nombre del atributo y del setter en tu action?

Comment: Si cambie todo , ya me salio amigo gracias

Comment: @KevinQuevedo ¿Podrías marcar las respuestas a tus preguntas como aceptadas, cuando te sirvan para solucionar tus problemas? Es el check que aparece al lado de la respuesta. Así, las preguntas quedan marcadas como *respondidas*.