# porque no me toma los txtbox en composite control?

Tags: windows-forms, app, aplicación-escritorio

arranque a estudiar y intentar hacer un proyecto que ya tengo en web forms,  y en el logueo no me toma los txt correspondientes para ingresar datos ( cedula por ejemplo) , aclaro ( solo por las dudas) que el form tiene un compositve control ,  alguien me puede orientar en que se basa mi error? teniendo en cuenta que en web estaba perfecto, el error deberia estar en los botones, alguna idea? 
dejo codigo completo del frm
public partial class FrmLogueo : Form
    {
        private Empleado _Empleado = null;
        private Login _Login = null;
        //public delegate void pasar(int cedula);
        //public event pasar pasarcedula;
        public FrmLogueo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void btnIniciarSesion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int cedula = 0;
        //string contraseña;
        try
        {
            int cedula = 0;
            string contraseña = "";
            try
            {
                cedula = Convert.ToInt32(_Login.Usuario);
            }
            catch
            {
                lblerror.Text = "Cedula Incorrecta";
            }
            try
            {
                contraseña = _Login.Contraseña;
            }
            catch
            {
                lblerror.Text = "Contraseña incorrecta";
            }
            ILogicaEmpleado LEmpleado = FabricaLogica.getLogicaEmpleado();
            _Empleado = LEmpleado.BuscarEmpleadoLogueo(cedula, contraseña);


            if (_Empleado == null)
            {
                lblerror.Text = "No existe el Empleado";

            }
            else
            {
                //pasarcedula(_Login.Usuario);
                FrmDefault _unfrm = new FrmDefault();
                _unfrm.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblerror.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private void login1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Por un lado, te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta para que sea un poco más legible, sino tus chanses de recibir una respuesta son sumamente bajas, por otro lado, **nunca JAMAS uses una ñ ni ningún acento en el nombre de una variable u objeto**, es pésima práctica

Comment: ok, solo quise plantear el problema bien, voy a cambiar la pregunta, que problema da la ñ ?

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [**esta respuesta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22393/77052) de [@Paula_plus_plus](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paula-plus-plus), que es simplemente espectacular y te va a quitar esa duda