# Saber si una cadena es numerica

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un trabajo y tengo una punto que no se exactamente si saldría bien o no.

Os cuento es un juego de cartas y tengo un atributo de la clase carta que es año de creación. para no andar con follones lo he puesto como String.

Ahora en el SET quiero verificar que la cadena que yo meto sea numérica y de 4 digitos.

Lo de la cadena numérica había pensado algo así

```
public void setAñoCreacion(String añoCreacion) {
    if(Integer.parseInt(añoCreacion)
        this.añoCreacion = añoCreacion
    }
}
```

Pero no me admite porque dice que no puede pasarse a boolean no entiendo porque no o es numérica o no lo es.
Gracias por echarme una mano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En la sentencia `if (condición)`, condición tiene que ser siempre un trozo de código equivalente a un booleano.

En tu código, utilizas la funcion `parseInt` para la condición:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(añoCreacion)) {
    this.añoCreacion = añoCreacion;
}
```

La función `parseInt` devuelve un dato de tipo int, por eso recibes el error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean

El if espera un **boolean** y tú le estás pasando un **int**. Hay varias formas de solucionar este problema, una de ellas podría ser utilizar la función `StringUtils.isNumeric`.

Para comprobar que el año tenga 4 dígitos, te sugiero que uses la función .length() de String, y finalmente el código quedaría así:

```
if (StringUtils.isNumeric(añoCreacion) && añoCreacion.length() == 4) {
    this.añoCreacion = añoCreacion;
}
```

Para usar la función isNumeric, tienes que añadir la librería correspondiente.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

Comment: Ojo, StringUtils pertenece a Apache Commons Lang y hay que importar la libreria externa si no no funciona. Se puede descargar de su página oficial https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Answer (score 4):

Hola para hacer más efectiva la comprobación de ambas cosas te dejo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
  String variableCorrecta = "2019";
  String variableValida = "abcd";
  String variableInvalida = "abcde";
  System.out.println("Probando con Variable Correcta: " + isValid(variableCorrecta));
  System.out.println("Probando con Variable Valida: " + isValid(variableValida));
  System.out.println("Probando con Variable Invalida: " + isValid(variableInvalida));

  public boolean isValid(String anio){
    if(anio.length()==4){
      try{
        System.out.println("Anio" + Integer.parseInt(anio));
        return true;
      }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("cumple la primer condición pero no es un entero");
        return false;
      }
    }else{
      System.out.println("No cumple la primer condición de tener una longitud de 4");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: no puedo poner print dentro de una clase o un metodo salvo en el main

Comment: @carlosdiaz no hace falta que uses los System.out.println, creo que los ha escrito para que entiendas mejor el flujo. Si quieres loggear información en la consola fuera del main, puedes utilizar algún Logger, por ejemplo el org.apache.log4j.Logger.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías comprobarlo con una expresión regular:

```
public void setAñoCreacion(String añoCreacion) {
    if(añoCreacion.matches("\\d{4}") { //el string está formado por 4 dígitos
        this.añoCreacion = añoCreacion;
    } else {
      throw new InvalidParameterException("...");
}
```

Por otro lado, te recomiendo leer [por qué no es bueno usar `ñ` o acentos en el código fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-%C3%91-en-nombre-de-variables/22393#22393).

Comment: Gracias ya he corregido lo de la ñ antes de leer el comentario jaj es un error de novato :P

Comment: Si se van a usar años negativos la expresión regular sería -?\d{4}

Comment: Por este medio doy la bienvenida a @carlosdiaz a Stackoverflow. En la pregunta leo esto: *para no andar con follones lo he puesto como String*  y me pregunto si precisamente lo que crees que te libera de *follones* lo que hace es liarte más. Si algo **ES** numérico **decláralo como tal** y controla el código donde tengas que controlarlo, por ejemplo, cuando el usuario ingresa los datos. Declarar un miembro de una clase de un tipo que no es el suyo me parece erróneo desde el punto de vista de la lógica y del diseño. La POO intenta precisamente que lo que programamos se ajuste a lo ***real***.

Comment: @A.Cedano siemrpe me han dicho qeu si es numerico pero no vas operar con el como un numero de telefono lo declare como String y ponerle DAte si solo va ser el año me parece ms coomodo pero dime tu idea

Comment: @carlosdiaz pues quien te haya dicho eso esta totalmente equivocado. Un tipo debe ser siempre declarado como su forma natural. Si es un numero es un numero. Si es un char un char, etc ....

Comment: @carlosdiaz lo de los números de teléfono es otra cosa (he visto discusiones sobre el tema particular en las que unos opinan que se debe declarar como numérico y otros como cadena, cada uno argumentando los motivos). En el caso que nos ocupa, un año es un valor numérico ¿?  es más, iría más lejos y me preguntaría por qué se desgaja un miembro de un elemento que es la fecha para ser tratado de forma particular ¿? Si un día el programa evoluciona y se requiere conocer el mes o el día de la creación de la carta, te vas a encontrar en un buen follón. Sugiero que diseñes conforme a la realidad.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma sencilla siguiendo lo que estabas usando es convertir a integer y comprobar el número de dígitos en función del valor:

```
try {
      if (Integer.parseInt(anoCreacion)>999) {
          this.anoCreacion = anoCreacion
      } 
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
```

También puedes añadir como condición adicional que sea menor de 10000 en caso de que pudiera haber más de 4 dígitos.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void setAñoCreacion(String añoCreacion) {
    if(Integer.parseInt(añoCreacion)
        this.añoCreacion = añoCreacion
    }
}
```

1. En tu bloque de código le falta un paréntesis
2. El error es porque Integer.parseInt(String) devuelve un entero, te faltaría compararlo con algo.
3. En el if, si introduces una cadena que no es numérica, te salta una excepción de parsing, deberías de:

```
try {
 Integer.parseInt(añoCreacion);
 this.añoCreacion = añoCreacion;
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
  // mensaje de error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes dejar el setter de la siguiente forma:

```
public void setAñoCreacion(int añoCreacion) {
    this.añoCreacion = añoCreacion
}
```

Y hacer tus verificaciones en otra parte, como por ejemplo en el evento keyPressed, ahi puedes verificar simplemente si la tecla presionada es numérica, así garantizas que el valor obtenido es numérico, después  con una condición verificas que el valor sea de 4 dígitos y lo envías al setter

Answer (score 1):

Para comprobar la longitud puedes usar el metodo `length` de String.

```
if(añoCreacion.length() == 4){
.....
}
```

Eso si yo no haria estas comprobaciones en el set sino antes.

Comment: Antes donde? a mi las comprobaciones me las han enseñado hacer en el set, por ejemplo que el precio sea mayor que 0. y lo de que sea numérica esta bien?

Comment: Un set unicamente debe asignar el valor, no debe hacer comprobaciones. Si lo haces en el set estas mezclando logica con modelo. El encargado de las comprobaciones tiene que ser el que crea el objeto, no el propio en si.

Comment: @JDev Si un setter simplemente asigna el valor no hay *valor añadido*: ¿Qué diferencia hay con exponer el atributo como público? Los setters están para controlar las modificaciones de los atributos

Comment: @PabloLozano es que un setter si tiene valor añadido pues dentro de el puedes modificar otros valores de la clase dependiendo del nuevo valor pero NUNCA debes hacer comprobaciones que hagan que no se asigne el valor.

Comment: @JDev Estoy de acuerdo en no *silenciar* el error, pero se puede hacer la comprobación y lanzar una excepción si el el valor no es válido

Comment: A mi me han enseñado a hacer las comprobaciones en el SET y luego en el constructor pones por ejemplo para el precio this.setPrecio

Comment: @PabloLozano no creo que sea lo mas correcto, le estas acoplando demasiada lógica a la clase.

Comment: @carlosdiaz eso si que no tiene sentido. Si usas los set es porque el objeto ya existe por lo que usar luego el constructor es ilogico.

Comment: @JDev Creo que se refiere a usar los setters en el constructor para *poblar* el objeto con los parámetros recibidos

Comment: Ah vale, eso si.

Comment: ¿Acaso un año es una cadena en la realidad, o es un número? Entonces lo que yo me pregunto es ¿por qué hay que declarar un año como un objeto del tipo `String`? A mi juicio ahí reside el punto de partida del error (de lógica, de diseño, de comprensión...), no se está programando conforme a la realidad, se está renunciando precisamente a lo que pretende la POO. Todo lo demás es secundario. El OP piensa que evitará follones declarando un año como String, pero haciendo eso lo que crea es un tremendo follón y confusión en el código.

Comment: @A.Cedano y cual es tu idea para que solo aparezca el año?

Comment: @carlosdiaz mi idea es controlar en otro punto. No veo por qué haya que cargar a la clase con una validación en el *setter*. Como digo, si un año es un número debe ser declarado como tal en la clase y controlar el código donde se alimenta a la clase. Dado que ese contexto falta en tu pregunta no puedo aportar ninguna respuesta. No se sabe si el punto de entrada es un escaner, un calendario, un textfield, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano entonces como declaro año para que solo me aparezca el año y obviamente solo meta el año como dato al crear el objeto carta puesto que es lo unico que piden?

Comment: @carlosdiaz lo lógico en ese caso es que el miembro `cardYear` (es preferible que nombres tus variables en inglés) de la clase sea del tipo `int`. Luego, para simplificar las cosas, en el punto de entrada puedes poner algo así como un combobox con todos los años disponibles donde el usuario seleccione uno para asignarlo como año de creación de la carta. Luego, si quieres más controles, puedes dotar a la clase de un método validador, el cual sería invocado desde el *setter* o bien desde donde se entran los datos (eso ya depende de la naturaleza de tu programa).

Comment: Si en tu programa por ejemplo se requiere validar en varios contextos un año, quizá convendría tener una clase Utilitaria y dentro de ella un método `isValidYear()` que se encargue de validar el año... supongamos que en el programa no se pueden admitir años menores a cierto valor (1910 por decir algo), toda esa lógica sería implementada en ese método, no en el *setter*  de una clase. Uno de los objetivos de la POO es reutilizar código y simplificar la complejidad de los programas.

Comment: @A.Cedano las clases de utilidad ya no se recomiendan. Te dejo un artículo interesante que explica el por qué https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/avoid-utility-classes/

Comment: Gracias por el enlace @Cristina. Aunque el autor pueda tener razón en algunas cosas (lo cual siempre es discutible y depende de muchos otros factores), lo que se pone en cuestión más que las clases utilitarias en sí, es la forma (tradicional) en que estás se han usado (declarándolas con final y estáticas). La clase utilitaria puede ser declarada como una clase normal e instanciarla cuando haga falta (a eso apunta la conclusión del artículo). En una app de considerable amplitud yo no veo mejor forma de implementar código que ha de usarse en varios puntos de dicha app como validaciones, formato

Comment: @A.Cedano en mi opinión, si necesitas hacer validaciones en diferentes sitios, puedes crear una clase de validación, por ejemplo, la cual puede ser reutilizada. El problema con las clases de utilidad es que aunque te permiten reutilizar código, acabas con una clase de 40000 líneas imposible de leer tipo "cajón de sastre". Claro que cada uno tiene su opinión al respecto, pero esto es un consenso y además va en contra del principio de responsabilidad única de SOLID. SOLID ahora es muy demandado para los programadores Java, así que encuentro importante conocer esto.