# Presencia de la letra 'ñ' en el nombre de una propiedad dentro de una expresión en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Probando AngularJS me encontré con una situación que me gustaría saber porqué ocurre.

Fíjense en el objeto `$scope.film` que está definido en el controlador que se ve acá abajo:

```
/* Modelo */
let app = angular.module('myApp', []);

/* Controlador */ 
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  /* Film */ 
  $scope.film = {
    titulo: 'Mad Max Fury Road',
    año: 2015
  };
}]);
```

Tal cual como está, es un objeto con una propiedad `titulo` y una propiedad `año`. En el caso de la propiedad `año`, está definida con la letra **ñ**.

```
$scope.film = {
    titulo: 'Mad Max Fury Road',
    año: 2015
};
```

Si yo quiero usar una expresión en una vista para imprimir el valor de la propiedad `año` del objeto, usando la sintaxis `objeto.propiedad`...

```
<!-- Vista -->
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <p>{{film.año}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

...obtengo un error:

> Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 6-6 [ñ] in expression [film.año].

Dándome a entender, de acuerdo a la documentación de referencia de errores de AngularJS, que el caracter **ñ** me genera un error léxico en la expresión:

> Occurs when an expression has a lexical error, for example a malformed number (0.5e-) or an invalid unicode escape.

Si por otro lado, uso la misma expresión para imprimir el valor de la propiedad `año` usando la sintaxis `objeto['propiedad']`, no genera ningún problema, y en la vista se me muestra el valor de esa propiedad.

```
<!-- Vista -->
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <p>{{film['año']}}</p> <!-- HTML: 2015 --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

## Snippet de prueba

Aquí lo pueden probar. Dejé comentada la expresión que no da errores.

```js
/* Modelo */
let app = angular.module('myApp', []);

/* Controlador */ 
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.film = {
    title: 'Mad Max Fury Road',
    año: 2015
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Vista -->
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <p>{{film.año}}</p>
    
    <!-- <p>{{film['año']}}</p> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Yo podría perfectamente usar la sintaxis `objeto['propiedad']` para imprimir mi valor de la propiedad, o cambiar el nombre de la propiedad de `año` a `annio` (u otros).

Pero el punto de mi pregunta es saber el porqué AngularJS no permite el uso de la letra **ñ** como parte del nombre de una propiedad, usando la sintaxis `objeto.propiedad` dentro de una expresión.

Comment: relacionada : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-%c3%91-en-nombre-de-variables

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta de porqué ocurría esta situación.

El caracter **ñ** no es parte del rango de caracteres por defecto que se pueden usar para las propiedades de los objetos en AngularJS, y por eso no lo puedo usar con la sintaxis `objeto.propiedad`.

Ese rango de caracteres está disponible en una función en el script `angular.js`, que dependiendo de las versiones de AngularJS con que se esté trabajando, puede tener un nombre distinto.

Por ejemplo, en [AngularJS 1.4.8](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js), esa función se llama `isIdent()`, mientras que en [AngularJS 1.7.8](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular.js), esa función se llama `isValidIdentifierStart()` (script no minificado, línea 15701):

```
isValidIdentifierStart: function(ch) {
    return ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z' ||
        'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ||
        '_' === ch || ch === '$');
},
```

Si por alguna razón hipotética, necesito trabajar con el caracter **ñ** usando la sintaxis `objeto.propiedad`, lo que tendría que hacer es modificar el script `angular.js`, agregando ese caracter a dicha función.

En el código que se ve abajo también agrego la misma letra pero en mayúscula:

```
/* Agrego ñ (minúscula) y Ñ (mayúscula) */
isValidIdentifierStart: function(ch) {
    return ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z' ||
        'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ||
        '_' === ch || ch === '$' || ch === 'ñ' || ch === 'Ñ');
},
```

Si así lo quisiera, podría definir un rango adicional de caracteres al ya existente, de modo que no solo puedo usar la ñ, sino otros caracteres con tilde o diéresis.

Supongamos que necesito usar todos los caracteres desde **À** hasta **ÿ**. Para ello necesito los números decimales correspondientes a dichos caracteres ([aquí hay una tabla extendida de codigos ASCII como referencia](https://www.ascii-code.com)) y el método `charCodeAt()`. Los dos me van a permitir definir los mínimos y los máximos de dichos rangos:

```
/* Agrego rango de caracteres desde À (192) hasta ÿ (255), 
   incluyendo ñ (241) y Ñ (209) */
isValidIdentifierStart: function(ch) {
    return ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z' ||
        'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ||
        '_' === ch || ch === '$') 
        || 192 <= ch.charCodeAt(0) && ch.charCodeAt(0) <= 255;
},
```

De esa manera, si quisiera, podría usar el carácter **à** (que está dentro del rango) y usarlo con mis propiedades de objetos.

```
/* Controlador */
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    /* Propiedad 'año' escrita con el caracter adicional à (224) */ 
    $scope.film = {
        titulo: 'Mad Max: Fury Road',
        àño: 2015
    };
}]);
```

Podría incluso ir mas allá y nombrar mi propiedad de `año` en mi objeto, solamente con los caracteres adicionales que definí, y seguiría funcionando.

**Módulo + Controlador**

```
/* Módulo */
let app = angular.module('myApp', []);

/* Controlador */ 
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    /* La propiedad 'año' del objeto está escrita solamente 
       con los caracteres adicionales à (224), ñ (241) y ö (246) */
    $scope.film = {
        titulo: 'Mad Max: Fury Road',
        àñö: 2015
    };
}]);
```

**Vista**

```
<!-- Vista -->
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <p>{{film.àñö}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Por supuesto, si así lo necesito, en todos los casos puedo usar la sintaxis `objeto['propiedad']`.

**Notas adicionales:**

- Solución basada en esta pregunta de Stack Overflow: [Angular js - Error: $parse:lexerr Lexer Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093660/angular-js-error-parselexerr-lexer-error)

Comment: mas alla de la buena respuesta,se acostumbra a declarar variables sin caracteres especiales

Comment: @JackNavaRow Si, es cierto, pero el punto de todo esto era ver que pasa si es que necesito usar esos caracteres especiales con la sintaxis `objeto.propiedad`. Es una situación límite que quería probar.

Answer (score 7):

A partir de [`AngularJS v1.5.4`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.4/docs/api/ng) se agregó el módulo [`ngParseExt`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.4/docs/api/ngParseExt) el cual:

> Proporciona funcionalidad para permitir caracteres `Unicode` en identificadores dentro de expresiones Angular.
>
> Este módulo permite el uso de cualquier identificador que siga la convención de nomenclatura de identificadores `ES6` para ser utilizado como un identificador en una expresión Angular. `ES6` delega algunas de las definiciones de reglas de identificación a `Unicode`, este módulo utiliza la convención de identificadores `ES6` y `Unicode 8.0`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
/* Modelo */
let app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngParseExt']);

/* Controlador */ 
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.film = {
    title: 'Mad Max Fury Road',
    àñö: 2015
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.4/angular-parse-ext.js"></script>

<!-- Vista -->
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <p>{{film.àñö}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: La idea que me gatilló proponer la situación que señalé al inicio, me vino de una aplicación web en AngularJS con la que estoy trabajando. Lamentablemente no la voy a poder probar en ella porque esto viene desde AngularJS 1.5.4, mientras que la aplicación con la que estoy trabajando usa AngularJS 1.4.8. Sea cual sea el caso, no se me había pasado por la cabeza que había un módulo para eso.

Comment: No hay drama, porque de todos modos la pregunta, tal cual como está planteada, no tiene énfasis en alguna versión en particular.