# JAVA - ¿Como hacer un 'log in' basico?

Tags: java

Hola queria saber si me puede ayudar a como verificar si los datos ingresados por el usuario son verdaderos en un simple "log in". Resumo el codigo a lo importante para que se entienda, suponiendo que ya estan los prints y todo...

```
    String nombre = "nestor";                               
    String pass = "nestor";

    String usuario = input.nextLine();
    String contraseña = input.nextLine();

    while (nombre != usuario && contraseña != pass)
```

No importa lo que escriba siempre me entra al while aunque el usuario ingrese el usuario y contraseña correctos.. ayuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes usar el equals en lugar el !=

```
String nombre = "nestor";                               
String pass = "nestor";

String usuario = input.nextLine();
String contraseña = input.nextLine();

while (!nombre.equals(usuario) && !contraseña.equals(pass)) {
    usuario = input.nextLine();
    contraseña = input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Perfecto!! asi sirve. Es medio rebuscado para la gente que viene de python jajaj..

Answer (score 3):

Para realizar una comparación de un String se debe utilizar: **equals** o **!equals**, cuando utilizas **!=** o **==** es para comparar enteros (comúnmente).

Dentro del while la condición ***&&*** yo la cambiaría por **||** ya que en un login si uno de los dos datos es incorrecto, no se permite el acceso.

De igual forma te comparto [Uso de Ñ en nombre de variables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-%c3%91-en-nombre-de-variables) para que determines que tan recomendable es hacer uso de estos caracteres.

```
    String nombre = "nestor";
    String pass = "nestor";

    System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre de usuario: ");
    String usuario = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa la contrasena: ");
    String contrasena = input.nextLine();

    while (!nombre.equals(usuario) || !contrasena.equals(pass)) {
        System.out.println("Credenciales incorrectas");
        System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre de usuario: ");
        usuario = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingresa la contrasena: ");
        contrasena = input.nextLine();

    }
    System.out.println("Credenciales correctas");
```

Answer (score 1):

cual es la necesidad de hacerlo con un while, si puedes hacer con un IF.

```
String nombre = "nestor";                               
String pass = "nestor";

String usuario =input.nextLine();
String contraseña = input.nextLine();

if(usuario != null && !usuario.isEmpty()){
    if(contraseña != null && !contraseña.isEmpty()){
        if(nombre.equals(usuario)){
            if(pass.equals(contraseña)){
                System.out.println("user logeado correctamente");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagino que es para que pueda ir probando passwords aunque falle la primera vez

Comment: porque con if solo entra una vez

Comment: Si tienes razón, para hacer pruebas te sirve, saludos