# Python 3 y ñ en variable

Tags: python, variables, python-3.7, unicode

Hola amigos disculpen tengo una duda  tengo mi script que empieza por estas lineas y me da error en la variable España por la ñ pero si ya puse la codificacion en las primeras lineas como podria usar variables con ñ?

```
     #!/usr/bin/python
     # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
     España=1
```

gracias por su tiempo y ayuda

Comment: ¿Seguro que usas un intérprete Python 3 y no Python 2? ¿Qué te muestra si añades la linea `import sys; print(sys.version)` al inicio del script eliminando la que ahora te da el error?

Comment: Lo digo porque Python 3 no tiene problema con usar identificadores no ASCII en UTF-8 (implementado a partir de [PEP 3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/)) pero en Python 2 los identificadores son cadenas de bytes, es decir letras ASCII y dígitos solo. Si usas Python 2 (probablemente /usr/bin/python sea un intérprete 2.7.X por lo comentado), considera abandonarlo, está en EOL, si usas Python 3 no necesitas declarar el encoding siquiera en éste caso, se usa UTF-8 tanto para código fuente como para cadenas y el código es totalmente correcto sintáxticamente.

Comment: Ya comprendi mi error si estaba sin darme cuenta usando el python 2.7 lo solucione haciendo python3 script.py y listo supongo que para correrlo desde la consola con el 3 abria que darle permisos con chmod +x y ponerle en el shebang  `#!/usr/bin/python3` ? correcto muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Relacionado: [Uso de letra **Ñ** en nombre de variables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-Ñ-en-nombre-de-variables)