# ejercicios de ciclos en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Buen dia

Realizando un ejercicio de condicionales la consola de google me bota el siguiente error:

```
Error de referencia no capturado el número no está definido en
```

salario.html: 30

La linea en la que me aparece el error es:

--  var nsueldo = number(elementoTxtSueldo.value);   --

utilice un --addEventListener-- quise ejecutar esta función y no encuentro errores.

Agradezco su tiempo y estoy atento a indicaciones

```js
var elementoTxtSueldo = document.getElementById("txtSueldo");
    var elementoTxtAños= document.getElementById("txtañosLaborados");
    var elementoTxtEvaluación = document.getElementById("txtEvaluación");


    var elementoBotonCalcular = document.getElementById("btnCalcual")
    elementoBotonCalcular.addEventListener("click", carcularAumento);

    var nsueldo = number(elementoTxtSueldo.value);
    var naños = number(elementoTxtAñosnumer.value);
    var ncalificacion = number(elementoTxtEvaluación.value);

    var naumento = 0;
    var nsueldoFinal = 0;

    function carcularAumento() {

      if (naños >2 ) {
        naumento+=(0.03* nsueldo);

      }

      if (nsueldo<2000 && naños>1) {
        naumento+=(0.25 * nsueldo);
      }

      if  (ncalificacion>8.7) {
        naumento+=(0.05*nsueldo);
      }

        if  (ncalificacion<6) {
          namento=0;
        }


        nsueldoFinal=nsueldo+naumento;

        document.write("el aumenmto es de " + naumento + "<br>");
        document.write("el sueldo con el aumento es igual a :" + nsueldoFinal);
        }
```

```html
  <form>
      <label for="txtSueldo">suelodo</label>
      <input type="number" id="txtSueldo">
      <label for="txtAñosLaborados">añosLaborados</label>
      <input type="number" id="txtAñosLaborados">
      <label for="txtEvaluación">Evaluación</label>
      <input type="number" id="txtEvaluación">

 <input type="button" id="btnCalcual" value="calcular aumento">

    </form>
```

ademas

Comment: Por favor coloca el mensaje de error tal cual aparece

Comment: No entiendo porque se pone la funcion number() cuando en el input ya se declara como type="number", y es recomendable no usar la ñ https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-%C3%91-en-nombre-de-variables

Comment: Buen dia @angel-reyna-torrejon, las Ñ no me deberian de molestar porque agregue la colección de caracteres especiales   <meta charset="utf-8">.  por otro lado un atributo tipo numero es para que me cree un cuadro de testo que solo agrega números pero la verdad no se si de manera natural el valor dado saldria como numero o texto ya que no logro que me funcione el codigo mas sin embargo muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Buen dia @BetaM adjunto un pantallaso con el error                                                
( https://postimg.cc/QFJL4rBX) .

Comment: Buen dia                                                                                                                            Se que mi error esta en las lineas:                                                                                      var nsueldo = number(elementoTxtSueldo.value);                                                             Mi idea con el .value es obtener el dato de la caja de texto pero la consola del navegaro bota error al intoducirlo.                                                                                        Gracias pór su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo visto llamas a una funcion `number()` no definida en el codigo. Suponiendo que lo que deseas hacer es convertir el texto del valor en un numero, la funcion debe ser `Number()`(notese la mayuscula al inicio, Javascript es un lenguage sensible a mayusculas/minusculas)

```
var nsueldo = Number(elementoTxtSueldo.value);
var naños = Number(elementoTxtAñosnumer.value);
var ncalificacion = Number(elementoTxtEvaluación.value);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number

Cabe destacar que tambien existe la funcion `parseFloat()` que en la mayoria de los casos entrega el mismo resultado, pero con algunas diferencias significativas en otros casos.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/parseFloat

Comment: buen dia gracias @f.lgor,  pero las funciones comienzan con minúscula y si la función contiene mas de una palabra la primera letra que conecta dichas palabras va en mayúscula como es el caso de parseFloat( ).  mas su sugerencia de cambio de funcion me hiso dar cuenta de otro error de codigo en mi ejercicio gracias.