# ¿por qué al recorrer el array la propiedad length se lee de manera inapropiada y arroja como resultado null?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, null

Comunidad ¡los saludo! Tengo un pequeño problema acá y es que cuando introduzco los datos de los 3 libros solicitados por prompt (titulo, autor, año y genero) al final no puedo salir simplemente con la tecla escape sino que debo darle varias veces hasta que agota el ciclo y luego por consola aparece este error "Cannot read property 'length' of null al line 38" la cual sería la que corresponde a año.length == 4 && y allí es cuando no consigo resolver la lógica de lo que esta pasando... gracias de antemano

```js
//Los datos los muestro por consola pero pido datos mediante prompt para interactuar con usuario.

alert('Introduzca la busqueda de 3 libros a continuacion: ');

class Book{
    constructor(titulo, autor, año, genero) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.año = año;
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    getAutor() {
        return this.autor;
    }

    getGenero() {
        return this.genero;
    }

    bookInfo() {
        return `${this.titulo} es un libro de ${this.genero} 
        escrito por ${this.autor} en el año ${this.año}`;
    }
}

let books = [];

while (books.length < 3) {
    let titulo = prompt("Introduzca el titulo del libro");
    let autor = prompt("Introduzca el autor del libro");
    let año = prompt("Introduzca el año de publicacion");
    let genero = prompt("Introduzca el genero literario");

    if(titulo != '' 
    && autor != '' 
    && !isNaN(año) && 
    año.length == 4 &&
    (genero == 'comedia' || genero == 'historia' || 
    genero == 'bibliografico' || genero == 'terror' || 
    genero == 'comedia')) {
        books.push( new Book(titulo, autor, año, genero));
    }
}

const mostrarLosLibros = () => {
    console.log(books);
}

const mostrarAutores = () => {
    let autores = [];

    for (const book of books) {
        autores.push(book.getAutor());
    }
    console.log(autores.sort());
}

const mostrarGeneros = () => {
    const genero = prompt("Introduce el genero que deseas buscar:");

    for (const book of books) {
        if(book.getGenero() == genero) {
            console.log(book.bookInfo());
        }
    }
}

mostrarLosLibros();
mostrarAutores();
mostrarGeneros();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La letra `ñ` no puede ser parte de un nombre de variable en ningún lenguaje de programación.

puedes leer más de ello en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22393/245572)

por ende no es usada y no identificada por el lenguaje y cae en un bucle infinito.

Comment: excelente @joseph-sx y agradezco tu observación y recomendación, pero más que una respuesta, esto es un comentario ya que al eliminar la ñ no se resuelve el problema. Puedes mirar cómo responder acá: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  y también pudes documentarte respecto al tema acá:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Una disculpa.
cuando insertas los datos lo haces cumpliendo las reglas del if? 
Veo que todas las condiciones son separadas por un AND excepto las del género.

ejecuté tu código con el cambio de la ñ y me funcionó correctamente.
si alguna de las condiciones no se cumple ese registro no es agregado al arreglo de libros y continuará pidiendo los datos hasta que las condiciones para agregarlo se cumplan y el arreglo llegue a 3 registros

Comment: Exacto, @joseph-sx estaba introduciendo los datos sin cumplir las condiciones del if. Ahora lo probé y funciona perfecto.