# agregar datos a un array y luego buscarlos

Tags: c++, array, estructuras-de-datos

en este programa quiero agregar elementos a un arreglo estatico, y luego a traves del dni poder buscarlos para posteriormente eliminarlos. Tengo todas las funciones, pero al cargar pacientes una y otra vez el nuevo paciente va "tapando" al anterior, y al buscarlo no aparece. 
No logro darme cuenta si el problema esta en el struct, en las funciones o que. Me recomendaron hacerlo en funciones asi el programa principal no tiene tanta carga. Dichas funciones estaran dentro de una funcion llamada menu, entonces el programa principal sera simplemente menu(); 
Recomendaciones??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

const long int MAX = 10000;

struct paciente{
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    int dni;
    int telefono;
};

int eliminar(paciente arreglo[], int tamaño, int elem){
    for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++){
        if (arreglo[i].dni == elem){
            for (int k = i; k < (tamaño-1); k++){
                arreglo[k].dni = arreglo[k+1].dni;
            }
            tamaño--;
            break;
        }
    }
    return tamaño;
}

int cargarpac(paciente arreglo[], int tamaño){
    int cuantos;

    cout << "Cuantos pacientes desea ingresar: " << endl; cin >> cuantos;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cuantos; i++){
            cout << "Ingrese su nombre: "; getline(cin >> ws, arreglo[i].nombre);
            cout << "Ingrese su apellido: "; getline(cin >> ws, arreglo[i].apellido);
            cout << "Ingrese su DNI: "; cin >> arreglo[i].dni;
            cout << "Ingrese su numero de telefono: "; cin >> arreglo[i].telefono;

            arreglo[tamaño].nombre = arreglo[i].nombre;
            arreglo[tamaño].apellido = arreglo[i].apellido;
            arreglo[tamaño].telefono = arreglo[i].telefono;
            arreglo[tamaño].dni = arreglo[i].dni;
            tamaño++;
            
    }
    return tamaño;
}

bool buscar(paciente arreglo[], int tamaño, int elim){
    for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++)
       if (arreglo[i].dni == elim)
            return true;
    return false;   
}

void mostrar(paciente datosPaciente[]){
    int i = 0;
    int dimlog = 1;
    while (i < dimlog){
        cout << "Nombre: " << datosPaciente[i].nombrepac << endl;
        cout << "Apellido: " << datosPaciente[i].apellido << endl;
        cout << "DNI:" << datosPaciente[i].dni << endl;
        cout << "Numero de telefono: " << datosPaciente[i].telefono << endl;
        i++;
    }
}

void admPacient();

paciente datosPaciente[MAX];
int dimlog = 0;

void altaPac(){

    cargarpac(datosPaciente, dimlog);
}

void bajaPac(){
    int elim;
    int deseo;

    cout << "Ingrese su DNI para darse de baja: "; cin >> elim;
    if (buscar(datosPaciente, dimlog, elim)){
        mostrar(datosPaciente);
        cout << "Si quiere darse de baja del sistema, presione 1. De lo contrario, presione 2" << endl; cin >> deseo; 
        if (deseo == 1){
            eliminar(datosPaciente, dimlog, elim);
        }
        else{
            getch();
        }
    }
    else{
        cout << "El paciente no se encuentra en el sistema" << endl;
    }
}

void admPacient(){
    char opcionpac;

    do{
    cout << "MENU DE ADMINISTRACION DE PACIENTES" << endl;
    cout << "[a] Alta de Pacientes." << endl;
    cout << "[b] Modificacion de Pacientes." << endl;
    cout << "[c] Baja de Pacientes." << endl;
    cout << "[d] Listado de Pacientes." << endl;
    cout << "[e] Volver al Menu Principal." << endl;

    cout << "Seleccione el menu al que desea acceder: "; cin >> opcionpac; opcionpac = tolower(opcionpac);

    switch(opcionpac)
    {
        case 'a':
        {
            system("cls");
            altaPac();
            break;
        }
        case 'b':
        {
            system("cls");
            modifPac();
            break;
        }
        case 'c':
        {
            system("cls");
            bajaPac();
            break;
        }
        case 'd':
        {
            system("cls");
            listaPac();
            break;
        }
        case 'e':
        {
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
         default:
        {
            cout << "La opcion ingresada es inexistente. Presione ENTER para regresar al menu anterior.";
            getch();
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
    }
        } while (opcionpac != 'e');
}            

void menu(){
    int opcion;

    do{
    cout << "BIENVENIDO AL MENU DE SALUD+." << endl;
    cout << "[1] Administrar Especialidades Medicas." <<endl;
    cout << "[2] Administrar Pacientes." << endl;
    cout << "[3] Administrar Turnos." << endl;
    cout << "[4] Salir." << endl;

    cout << "Seleccione el menu al que desea acceder: "; cin >> opcion;

    switch (opcion)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            system ("cls");
            admEspMed();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            system ("cls");
            admPacient();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            system ("cls");
            admTurnos();
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        default:
        {
            cout << "La opcion ingresada es inexistente. Presione ENTER para regresar al menu anterior.";
            getch();
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
    }
    }while (opcion != 4);
}          

//PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL
int main()
{
    menu();

    return 0;
}
```

gracias!!

Comment: `int tamaño` nunca utilices estos caracteres raros en tus variables... lectura recomendada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22360/uso-de-%C3%91-en-nombre-de-variables

Comment: `mostrar(datosPaciente);` donde declaras esta esta función?

Comment: se me habia olvidado copiarla, ahi edite

Comment: Solo veo que declaras funciones, donde está tu `int main()`? como corres el proyecto sin esto??

Comment: no quise ponerlo para no cargar la pregunta de codigo... ahi agrego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable `tamaño` de la función `cargarpac` es una copia de la variable global `dimlog`, cuando incrementas la variable `tamaño` no estás afectando a los datos de `dimlog`.

Probablemente querías usar una referencia:

```
int cargarpac(paciente arreglo[], int &tamaño){
//                    Referencia ---> ^
    int cuantos;

    cout << "Cuantos pacientes desea ingresar: " << endl; cin >> cuantos;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cuantos; i++){
            cout << "Ingrese su nombre: "; getline(cin >> ws, arreglo[i].nombre);
            cout << "Ingrese su apellido: "; getline(cin >> ws, arreglo[i].apellido);
            cout << "Ingrese su DNI: "; cin >> arreglo[i].dni;
            cout << "Ingrese su numero de telefono: "; cin >> arreglo[i].telefono;

            arreglo[tamaño].nombre = arreglo[i].nombre;
            arreglo[tamaño].apellido = arreglo[i].apellido;
            arreglo[tamaño].telefono = arreglo[i].telefono;
            arreglo[tamaño].dni = arreglo[i].dni;
            tamaño++;
            
    }
    return tamaño;
}
```

Con una referencia se actualiza automáticamente la variable referenciada. ¿O tal vez pretendías guardar el valor después de la llamada usando el valor de retorno?

```
int dimlog = 0;

void altaPac(){

    dimlog = cargarpac(datosPaciente, dimlog);
}
```